# Output current of 1 Pin (New Model)

Tags: gpio, output

Quick question. I have the latest Raspberry Pi (Model 3B+) and I just want to know if the **output current** of the 3.3 V supply has changed as I'm using a T-cobbler at the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done quite a bit of research and testing on the circuitry introduced by the PiB+ which was used in later models - up to Pi3. The regulator which supplies 3.3V is rated at 1A, and tested up to 800mA - See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

The Pi3B+ has a new regulator chip, the 3.3V supply regulator is rated at 1.5A, although I have not conducted any load testing. It may be able to supply more than the Pi3B, but is still limited by the PSU and polyfuse.